# Does Castle Crashers allow Local and Online Coop simultaneously?

Tags: pc, castle-crashers

For example, two players with separate controllers connected to the same machine, and another player over the Internet.

Comment: I would like to add that this is possible on consoles. You can play online with multiple controllers connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My play testing shows that it does not.  It is either local co-op or online co-op.